# Create a C#/.Net json date in php

Tags: c#, php, .net, json, date-format

How can I create a date string in PHP that can be read by .NET's non standard date format:

eg Given this PHP code:

```
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT birthday FROM people"); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $birthday = $row['birthday'];
    $json = ??? // some way to convert it to the .net json format
}
```

How can I manipulate that PHP date to return this style of JSON as expected by C#/.Net's json deserialize method:

```
{"birthday":"\/Date(1331550000000)\/"}
```

Answer (score 3):

The .NET format is Milliseconds from the Epoch - so the following format worked for me

```
 $date = '/Date('.(date("U",time())*1000).'-0500)/';
```

Answer (score 0):

.Net's json deserialize method can accept any json data. You could build the json like below.

```
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT birthday FROM people"); 
$birthdays = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $birthdays[] = $row;
}
$json = json_encode($birthdays);
echo $json;
```

Comment: Unfortunately the remote server I am connecting to will only accept one exact date format: `\/Date(1331550000000)\/` and throws an exception if any other format is sent.

Comment: @JK What is your birthday like?

Comment: Lol, thats a bit personal isnt it, I hardly know you :)  (Its a standard mysql datetime column)

Comment: @JK SO you want to turn date to a timestamp? But you should know you should not use timestamp to present birthday.